# How to make array data in custom jQuery Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for some tutorial to make an array data in custom jQuery Function, but I can't find any. Can you tell me how to make an array in jQuery Function? I want to call my function like this :

```
$(this).myPlugin({ 
    data_first: '1'
    data_second: 'Hello'
});
```

**my function script**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(data) {
       return this.each(function() {
          alert(data[data_first]+' bla bla '+ data[data_second]);
       });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will wan't this.

```
alert(data.data_first+' bla bla '+ data.data_second);
```

Then you won't be trying to pass a `variable`

That is a `Object` you're using not an `Array`

You can get values from a `Object` like this

```
data.data_first; // By string name thing

data['data_first']; // By String Name

var index = 'data_first';
data[index]; // By variable
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass the array use:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(array) {
   console.log(array[0] + array[1]);

};
```

and call

```
$(this).myPlugin(['1', 'Hello']);
```

just like normal function